# How to get text inside a span Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to make a check for the appearance of text on the page that is inside 
The text looks something like "Constantly different nickname" + "Constantly the same text" on the same line.
I tried to make it like this

```
s = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='has joined & will be ready to chat in just a minute.']").text()
print(s)
```

And many more different attempts, but nothing worked
I need to get the whole string when its permanent part appears on the page

Answer (score 1):

Use expected conditions to wait until an element appears on the page. Set an appropriate amount of seconds in WebDriverWait that you think the element should appear.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='has joined & will be ready to chat in just a minute.']"))
)
```

Read also the docs regarding Waits: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Use visibility here since this just checks to see if the element is there.

Comment: True as he cleary mentioned "appearence", thank you @Arundeep Chohan. I edited my answer.